# Yii, How to submit a CActiveForm without a button by AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii, form-submit

I'm trying to make a CActiveForm containing a single textField to submit without a submit button, but I need it to call the action via AJAX !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "submit" it via ajax you need to bind a click event to your button:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){

});
```

Then to get the form data to submit use `$('#myForm').serializeArray()` which will return an object to use as the `data` option in your ajax request.

If you can't piece it together from that you need to do some more reading on Ajax, events and form data.

You can read about [jQuery AJAX here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**P.S**: I'm assuming jQuery because you're using Yii, you should really tag the question with jQuery too.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the `CHtml::submitButton()` with `CHtml::ajaxSumbitButton()` details here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxSubmitButton-detail

This will submit the form using ajax rather than a standard form submission

Edit:

Just re read the question and noticed the 'without' button bit...

If you're not submitting the form on a button click, just attach the jQuery to the action you want to submit the value, you can use the `CHtml::ajax()` helper for this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajax-detail

Comment: Why have I never noticed that before, works better than my method :)